# What ecs cluster mean in real application?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to learn what cluster in ecs means.

So [I found that in aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/clusters.html)  "Cluster — A logic group of EC2 instances." - what does it mean? How many clusters/services/tasks should I create? Is it one cluster for my application? or my organization?

Can somebody explain to me please what is cluster and service and task in aws ecs but in the real application? say I have a website `facebook.com` and how it fit to aws ecs terminology?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume facebook.com comprises several microservices - `auth`, `social` and `marketplace` to name a few.

We can deploy them to ECS this way:

1. a cluster per environment: `test.facebook.com`, `staging.facebook.com` and `prod.facebook.com`
2. a service per microservice. So it'll be `auth`, `social` and `marketplace` services
3. a task per instance of each microservice. Since we want `facebook.com` to be realiable, we'll add redundancy - there'll be multiple instances of each microservice